# Escolher um diretório para salvar arquivo javascript?

Tags: javascript

Pessoal da empresa esta me pedindo pra modificar o salvar da minha função, ela esta funcionando normal, só que eles querem escolher o diretório para salvar o `txt`, código da função é esse

```
function salvar() {

  let data = new Date().toLocaleDateString().slice(0,10);
  var texto = document.getElementById('conteudo').innerText;
  let titulo = document.getElementById('nomeCliente').value;
  let CodCli = document.getElementById('CodCliente').value;

  var blob = new Blob([texto], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });

  saveAs(blob, titulo + " " + CodCli + " " + data + ".txt");
}
```

eu já procurei pelo `File Dialog`, mas não obtive exito alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Imagino que você esteja forçando um download do blob na função `saveAs`. Se for isso, aparecer ou não a caixa de diálogo depende da configuração do browser. O browser não te dá acesso à manipulação de file dialogs via JS por questões de segurança.

Comment: como posso alterar isso?

Comment: Nas opções do browser geralmente você pode escolher se os downloads são automaticamente salvos numa pasta, ou se o browser deve perguntar sempre onde salvar. Onde isso fica exatamente vai depender do browser, e esse ajuste vai valer para todos os sites acessados por aquele navegador naquela máquina.